# Regex match URL that does not contain strings but also contains other string

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to match and replace asset URLs from a specific folder, without affecting other URLs in my .htaccess file. I have the .htaccess side of things down, am just struggling hardcore to match the correct URLs.

Given these three URLs:

- `http://nia.wp/wp-includes/fonts/tinymce.ttf`
- `http://nia.wp/wp-content/plugins/fonts/Bootstrap-Shortcodes-for-WordPress.ttf`
- `http://nia.wp/wp-content/themes/fonts/Bootstrap-Shortcodes-for-WordPress.ttf`

I only want to match the last one (containing `themes`), and for that matter everything after `/fonts/`

## current method matches everything:

`RewriteRule /?fonts/(.*)$ wp-content/themes/ng-health/app/fonts/$1 [NC,L]`

## trying to use a negative lookahead, but doesn't work:

`http:\/\/.+(?!wp-includes|plugins)\/fonts\/(.*)` (matches everything: http://regexr.com/39vka)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

- Instead of using a negative look ahead use a **negative look behind**

Regex can be

```
http:\/\/.+(?<!wp-includes|plugins)\/fonts\/.*
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/tE0dL9/1

**Change made**

- `(?<!wp-includes|plugins)` negative look behind. Assertst that `/fonts/` is not presceded by `wp-includes` or `plugins`

Comment: `http:\/\/.+(?<!wp-includes|plugins)\/fonts\/(.*)$` matched and grabs `fontname.tff` for me :D

Comment: Hey @nu11p01n73R, this demo isn't working anymore - can't figure out why!?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tE0dL9/7 - this should technically only match the last one right?

Comment: @harelpls The output you got is expected of the regex. By regex the `styles` must not be immediatly presceded by `plugins or wp-includes` which is true for the first and second input. Could you give a more explanation on what to match

Answer (score 0):

Try this also.

```
http:\/\/(?:(?!themes).)*themes\/fonts\/.*
```

**SEE DEMO :** http://regex101.com/r/fW1iC9/1

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the accepted one is a little better for me because I would rather exclude directories to rewrite than include ones to rewrite (as there are lots!)